# Remove rows having same name (different values)

Tags: r

Ex:Assume a data frame I/P
Name value

```
A.          10
A.          20
B.          30
B.          40
```

As per my requirements ,
O/p:

```
A.        10
B.        30
```

Alone and remove other  duplicate values of A& B

Answer (score 1):

Remove Duplicates -

**Based on single column**

```
df[!duplicated(df$V1),]

  V1 V2
1  A 10
3  B 30
```

**Based on all columns**

```
unique(df)

  V1 V2
1  A 10
2  A 20
3  B 30
4  B 40
```

**Based on subset columns**

Change the data to review output -

```
A,10,10
A,20,20
B,30,20
B,40,20
```

Now let's say we want to filter duplicates based on `V1` and `V3` -

```
df[!duplicated(df[ , c(1,3) ]), ]

  V1 V2 V3
1  A 10 10
2  A 20 20
3  B 30 20
```

Answer (score 1):

If there multiple rows create separate data frame for A and B
then select first row and first column.

```
 df1[1,1]

 df2[1,1]
```